# What's the differences between pseudospin and spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, group-theory

It seems that they both transform as an $SU(2)$ group, but I've been told that the three components of real spin change signs under inversion while it is not the case for pseudospin.

Could someone name all their similar and different properties? The more exhaustive, the better.

Answer (score 1):

The use of pseudospin appears to solve the problem of quasi-degeneracy of states. In relativistic quantum mechanics we know that when the sum of scalar and vector potential is null ($\Delta = S(r) + V(r) = 0$) we have spin symmetry. However, when the difference between scalar and vector potential is null ($\Sigma = S(r) - V(r) = 0$) we have pseudospin symmetry. Ginnochio has been shown that in some sort of problem the group symmetry may be defined as SU(2)xU(3).

We can search more articles of Ginnochio or Jia et al. on network. They explained a lot of these things more detailed. However, I never saw some article talking about geometry or the form of this symmetry of pseudospin. Maybe the treatment and approximation shall be only over the theory. This is my guess :)